# upload file to upload box using selenium webdriver

Tags: upload, box

I am trying to upload image to web site via upload box
but the problem is that upload box does not accept any values
any try to send image to that upload box just opens it but can not send image path to it

how to deal with windows download box

Answer (score 0):

You should first inspect the page (F12) and identify the xpath of the input webElement (could be something like this: //div[@id='input_field']).

Then you should use the selenium keyword '**choose file(locator,file_path)**'.[Selenium Keywords](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Choose%20File)

I see that you also mentioned 'download box' in your question,if you have another question about that please create another question and I could answer it.

```
Wait Until Element is Enabled   //button[@id='upload1btn']
Choose File   //button[@id='upload1btn']   path_to_file
```

#COMMENT: DO NOT FORGET IMPORT OF SELENIUM LIBRARY

Comment: I am using inspecting page and I can send data to text boxes but i can not upload images to upload box

Comment: when I use selenium web driver to  click the upload button inside a web site it shows me dialog box to choose file to upload , how to choose file from that dialog box using selenium web driver.....this is the upload button html syntax (<button id="upload1btn" name="upload1btn" type="button" onclick="clickUploadInput(1)" class="">Upload</button>)